# Is there subject or object being omitted in clauses e.g. 'As will be demonstrated in... ','As this brief outline indicates'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

There are many sentences like these:

> 1. As this brief outline indicates, from the point of view of reporting
>    structures, the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or
>    'ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their
>    opinions on them.
> 2. As will be demonstrated in Chapter 8, the subject of a clause plays an
>    important role; nonetheless, in a given clause the verb controls the
>    subject noun too.

Some say 'as' has the part of speech of 'pronoun', so it can function like 'which'.

But, in most of the main dictionaries, there is not any item with a 'pronoun' interpretation. So,can we think that the subject or object is omitted in the sentence?

> 1. As this brief outline indicates **[the idea]**, from the point of view of reporting
>    structures, the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or
>    'ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their
>    opinions on them.
> 2. As **[it]** will be demonstrated in Chapter 8, the subject of a clause plays an
>    important role; nonetheless, in a given clause the verb controls the
>    subject noun too.

Comment: "As" is here a preposition introducing that preposition phrase "as this brief outline indicates", which is functioning as an adjunct. of comparison.

Comment: @BillJ What is the object of 'indicates'?

Comment: The clausal complement of "indicates" is recoverable from the matrix, in this case the clause _the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or 'ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their opinions on them_.

Comment: @BillJ So, a pronoun referring to 'the reader...on them' is omitted,right ?

Comment: Yes, the comparative clauses functioning as complement to "as" are structurally incomplete.

Comment: In full it would be _this brief outline indicates the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or 'ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their opinions on them_.

Comment: @Bill Thanks. You can give an answer not just comments 

Comment: I've posted an answer, as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] [*As this brief outline indicates* ___ ] *, from the point of view of reporting structures, the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or*
> '*ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their*
> *opinions on them*.
>
> [2] [*As ___ will be demonstrated in Chapter 8*]*, the subject of a clause plays* *an important role*] ...

In both examples, the comparative clauses functioning as complement to the preposition "as" are structurally incomplete in that the clausal complements which their verbs would have in main clauses are missing.

The clausal complement of "indicates" and "will" are recoverable from the matrix.

In [1] what is indicated is that the reader of a news story expects to find 'important' or 'ordinary' people as speakers giving their account of events and their opinions on them.

And in [2] what will be demonstrated in Ch.8 is that the subject of a clause plays an important role.

Comment: Why do you insist that 'as' is a preposition, not a conjunction?

Comment: In modern grammar "as" is a preposition in examples like yours. This dictionary is up-to-date [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/as).

Answer (score 1):

*as*  is a conjunction here as described in [CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as).

> As as a conjunction
> We also use as to mean ‘in the way that’:
> *As* the forecast predicted, the weather was dreadful for the whole of the weekend.

Your examples hence could be read as

> **In the way that** this brief outline indicates, from the point of view of reporting structures, the reader of a news story expects to find ...

> **In the way that** will be demonstrated in Chapter 8, the subject of a clause plays an important role ...

Comment: In 'In the way that', which part of the speech is 'that'? And also,in [oxfordlearnersdictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_3), 'as' is defined as 'in the way in which'. So, is 'that' in 'In the way that' the same as 'in which'?

Comment: @Mr.Wang "That" is a relative pronoun in this context, and it can be replaced by "which", which is also a relative pronoun. "*In the way that*" is roughly the same as "*In the way which*". "In which" is not equivalent to either. "*In which this brief outline indicates, ...*" is nonsensical.

Comment: @gotube It is confusing. In [oxfordlearnersdictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/as_3) ,'as' is defined as 'in the way in which' in 'Leave the papers as they are.' ,but defined as 'in the way that' in ' We’d better leave things as they are until the police arrive.' in [LongMan](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as)

Comment: No. "as" is not a conjunction; it's a preposition. And "that" is not a relative pronoun; it's a subordinator (your conjunction) that introduces certain relative clauses, and declarative content clauses.

Comment: "As" is here a preposition introducing that preposition phrase "as this brief outline indicates", functioning as an adjunct of comparison.

Comment: @BillJ If it is a preposition,the phrase should be 'as this brief outline indicating'?

Comment: @Mr.Wang No: that would make no sense. However, in the right context, you could say _as this brief outline is indicating_ .

Comment: @Mr.Wang Good find. Both of your sourced definitions are correct, and make sense together if you know another grammar point: in "*the way in which they are*", the "in" is optional, and doesn't change the meaning if you include it: "*Leave the papers in the way (in) which they are*". But you cannot add "in" if you replace "which with "that":  "*Leave the papers in the way that they are*" (not "in that they are").